# How to use foreach php code in registerJS() javascript code in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I can't use foreach php code in javascript code of registerJS in yii2. Browser shows "PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)" error. Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="bar-chart" width="500" height="150"></canvas>

<?php 
$lang = Yii::$app->language;
$title = 'title_'.$lang;

$this->registerJs("
                new Chart(document.getElementById('bar-chart'), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                  labels: [
                                " . foreach ($models as $model) { . "
                                    ' " . $model->$title . " ',
                               " . } . "
                           ],
                  datasets: [
                    {
                      label:'Label',
                      backgroundColor: ['#3e95cd', '#8e5ea2','#3cba9f', '#e7fc00'],
                      data: [479,1654,499, 2632]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                options: {
                  legend: { display: false },
                  title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Title'
                  }
                }
            });
    ", yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: I'm using php 5.5 version

Comment: Did i write right php codes in js code my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll pull out foreach code from javascript output.

```
<?php 
$titles = [];
foreach($models as $model)
{
    $titles[] = sprintf("'%s'", $model->title);
}

$titlesText = implode(',', $titles);

$this->registerJs("
                new Chart(document.getElementById('bar-chart'), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                  labels: [ 
                      ".$titlesText."
                           ],
                  datasets: [
                    {
                      label:'Label',
                      backgroundColor: ['#3e95cd', '#8e5ea2','#3cba9f', '#e7fc00'],
                      data: [479,1654,499, 2632]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                options: {
                  legend: { display: false },
                  title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Title'
                  }
                }
            });
    ", yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `foreach` statement there, in the middle of a string. You should generate the string coming from the `foreach` beforehand and then join it with the js string:

```
$mystring = "";
foreach ($models as $model) { 
  $mystring .= "' " . $model->$title . " ',";
}

$this->registerJs("
                new Chart(document.getElementById('bar-chart'), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                  labels: [ $mystring ],
                  datasets: [
                    {
                      label:'Label',
                      backgroundColor: ['#3e95cd', '#8e5ea2','#3cba9f', '#e7fc00'],
                      data: [479,1654,499, 2632]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                options: {
                  legend: { display: false },
                  title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Title'
                  }
                }
            });
    ", yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: @AlisherNasrullayev dont forget to mark the answer correct if it solved your problem. (y)